# Liquibase Delimiter Issue T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, liquibase

I'm having trouble getting a new stored procedure added into my DB through Liquibase. The stored procedure works great on my local copy of this database, but I just can't get Liquibase to take it.

Here is my most recent error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

I believe there is an `OR` between the two `WHEN` statements, but I'm not 100% sure.

Does anyone see an issue with my code. Thanks in advance!

```
-- changeset Conner:492 splitStatements="false" endDelimiter=";":/
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateOrInsertWinningColorsAnswers(@json NVARCHAR(max)) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO WinningColorsAnswer W
    USING(
            SELECT *
            FROM OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH(
                Id int,
                Answer varchar(max),
                QuestionId int,
                SectionId int,
                StudentChallengeMappingId int,
                CreatedDate datetime2,
                CreatedUser varchar(20),
                UpdatedDate datetime2,
                UpdatedUser varchar(20),
                IsDeleted bit        
            )
        ) as InputJSON (Id,
                Answer,
                QuestionId,
                SectionId,
                StudentChallengeMappingId,
                CreatedDate,
                CreatedUser,
                UpdatedDate,
                UpdatedUser,
                IsDeleted)
    ON(W.StudentChallengeMappingId = InputJSON.StudentChallengeMappingId and W.QuestionId = InputJSON.QuestionId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET W.Answer = InputJSON.Answer,
            W.UpdatedDate = Convert(datetime, InputJSON.UpdatedDate, 104),
            W.UpdatedUser = InputJSON.UpdatedUser
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(Answer,QuestionId,SectionId,StudentChallengeMappingId,CreatedDate,CreatedUser,UpdatedDate,UpdatedUser,IsDeleted)
        VALUES(InputJSON.Answer,
        InputJSON.QuestionId,
        InputJSON.SectionId,
        InputJSON.StudentChallengeMappingId,
        Convert(datetime, InputJSON.CreatedDate, 104),
        InputJSON.CreatedUser,
        Convert(datetime, InputJSON.UpdatedDate, 104),
        InputJSON.UpdatedUser,
        Cast(InputJSON.IsDeleted as bit))
    ;
END
/
```

Comment: Firstly, when calling from Liquibase should you be starting your command with `GO`? Pretty sure that only works in SSMS. Secondly I suspect `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE` is not supported. What happens if you do `ALTER PROCEDURE`

Comment: @DaleK I will try running `Create Procedure` because this is a new stored procedure. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @DaleK That worked! I took out the `GO` and made it just `Create Procedure` and it was successful. Thank you!